# Wicket: ListView - skipping an item

Tags: java, listview, wicket

is it possible to skip an item in `populateItem()` ? e.g. by setting something on the item component, or whatever.

```
ListView view = new ListView("quickLinks", quickLinks) {
    @Override
    protected void populateItem( ListItem item ){
        if( item.getModel(). /*something*/ )
                    item.skip()
    }
};
```

Thanks

Comment: I haven't been able to find the information again but I faintly recall that Wicket 1.5 will incorporate a more generic rendering / iteration model for `ListView` s etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the [`iterator()`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/list/ListView.html#iterator%28%29) method in your `ListView` in order to only iterate the item you wish to render.

Comment: +1, but implementing iterators is tough. I'd recommend doing it with some helper method like [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/)'s [`Iterators.filter(Iterator, Predicate)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#filter%28java.util.Iterator%2C%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29)

Comment: Or the equivalent [`FilteredIterator(Iterator, Predicate)`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/iterators/FilterIterator.html)from [commons-collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections) if you prefer that

Comment: Is this solid? I mean, Wicket will never access the items other ways?

Comment: @Ondra Žižka I'm not sure whether Wicket guarantees this.

Comment: Would not do this, you are filtering on view not on model

Answer (score 10):

I would prefer filtering my model instead of doing an if / else check in the view.

Here, use this abstract class:

```
public abstract class FilteredListModel<K> extends LoadableDetachableModel<List<K>>{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private IModel<List<? extends K>> inner;

    @Override
    protected void onDetach(){
        inner.detach();
    }

    public FilteredListModel(IModel<List<? extends K>> inner){
        this.inner = inner;
    }
    public FilteredListModel(List<? extends K> inner){
        this.inner = Model.ofList(inner);
    }

    @Override
    protected final List<K> load(){
        List<? extends K> input = inner.getObject();
        List<K> result = new ArrayList<K>(input.size());
        for(K k : input){
            if(accept(k))result.add(k);
        }
        return result;
    }

    protected abstract boolean accept(K k);
}
```

Now wrap your list model into it:

```
ListView<String> view = new ListView<String>(
    "quickLinks",
    new FilteredListModel<String>(quickLinks){

      protected boolean accept(String value){
          return yourCheckHere();
      }

    }) {

    @Override
    protected void populateItem( ListItem<String> item ){
        // no ifs here
    }
};
```

Comment: Nice, I think I will use it in my Wicket 1.4 apps. Thanks!

Comment: Nice solution - also generic - goes right to my Utils ;)

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't `item.setVisible(false)` work?

Comment: Sure, but you would still have to create the components inside the item (or else the Java tree doesn't match the HTML tree). And I wouldn't like to create components that will never be used.

Comment: but it's only the short term memory on the server. the html won't be rendered - or am I wrong?

Comment: they are, but I have a List<Object> provided from backend, which contains various entities of mixed types, which may be added as time goes. My component can only render some of them. I know, not quite nice, but that's how the backend comes to me.

Comment: This does work and you don't have to create hierarchy after this call, wicket won't complain. I think this is the simplest and preferred method.